# Передать переменную за пределы функции

Tags: javascript, переменные, функции

У меня есть такой код

```
var db = openDatabase('webdatabases', '1.0', '', 2*1024*1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logistic (id unique, log)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO logistic (id, log) VALUES (0, "foobar")');
});

function sql_result(tx, results) {
var
len = results.rows.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
logi = results.rows.item(i).log;
// здесть есть переменная logi мне нужно чтоб она была доступна вне всех функций
}
}

db.transaction(function (tx) {
 tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM logistic', [], sql_result);
});
```

Как например здесь я могу получить переменную logi

Comment: Не пойму здесь что ограничено количество коментариев ?
NoName,
Я был глуп и не знал что
eee = function() {logi = 1;return logi;}();alert(eee) // выдаст 1
а 
eee = function() {logi = 1;return logi;};alert(eee) // выдаст функцию
продолжаю учить и узнавать
но в моем примере
eee = function sql_result(tx, results) {
len = results.rows.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
logi = results.rows.item(i);
}
return logi;
}()
alert(eee);
не выдает значение переменной logi

Answer (score 3):

достаточно всего лишь объявить эту переменную вне функции

Comment: Мне нужно получить значение переменной logi из функции sql_result. Если объявить эту переменную вне функции то она будит undefined

Comment: ну так и возвращайте её через return тогда

Comment: function sql_result(tx, results) {
 var
  len = results.rows.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
  logi = results.rows.item(i).log;
 }
 return logi;
}
db.transaction(function (tx) {
 tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM logistic', [], eee);
});
// Здесь она все равно не доступна, попробуйте сами.

Comment: ну как недоступна? Смотрим: http://jsfiddle.net/CaW7C/

Здесь, конечно, кое-что изменено, убрана специфика, чтобы пример, вырванный из контекста, мог работать. Смотрим внимательно: объявляется переменная, в неё записывается что вам нужно, и эта переменная возвращается return'ом. И всё работает, значение доступно за пределами функции. Вроде всё предельно просто.

Comment: Вернемся в начало. Посмотри в код приведенный вверху, мне нужно получить данные из базы браузера а затем передать в php. Для этого я использовал код из мануала. Но возникла проблема, как я понял это работает следующим образом:
db.transaction выполняет запрос вызывает функцию sql_result и передает данные в нее. по идее в переменной logi должны сохранится данные и когда я в любом месте алертну logi он должен мне выдать "foobar" но это не работает. В твоем примере results объявляется в функции, так канечно же ретурн и все.

Comment: Обращаясь к **logi** без **var** Вы обращаетесь к глобальной переменной.  
В любом другом месте Вы можете обратиться к ней так же без **var**.

Comment: окей, вот пример с вашей спецификой: http://jsfiddle.net/CaW7C/1/

По прежнему всё выводится

Comment: > В любом другом месте Вы можете обратиться к ней так же без var

и получить ошибку logi is not defined

Comment: тогда мне следует сделать так
eee = function sql_result(tx, results) {
len = results.rows.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
logi = results.rows.item(i);
}
return logi;
}

alert(logi);

но это не работает

Comment: скорее `alert(eee);`

Comment: Всю жизнь думал, что  

    function () {
        foo = 'bar';
    }();
Установит глобальную переменную `foo`.  
Повсеместное использование `var` не давало мне наткнуться на то, что я заблуждаюсь.  
Век живи- век учись.

Comment: Я не пишу на JS, но тут очевидно, что речь о глобальных переменных. Вопрос в гугле

    javascript глобальные переменные

тут же выводит на [Область видимости переменной в Javascript (ликбез)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/78991/), где обсуждается подобный вопрос и расписываются правила объявления и использования глобальных переменных в JS.

--

Насколько я успел узнаь эту тему, @Елена Левина, ответила правильно, но не полно.

В простом случае переменная будет глобальной если она определена и ей присвоили значение вне функции до вызова функции.

Comment: [Форкнул](http://jsfiddle.net/ReinRaus/CaW7C/2/), а то ТС так и не понял как это сделать, поэтому задал еще один вопрос.